# Count the number of distinct values in a column - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Is it possible to have the summary below in one textbox within the same column:

```
Apple
Banana
Apple
Banana
Banana
Orange
```

**Output:**

**Apple:** 2
**Banana:** 3
**Orange:** 1

Comment: Yes this is possible. you can easily find this out yourself if you look for the functionality of `GROUP BY` in SQL.

Comment: hi @GiorgosBetsos I'm referring to SSRS

Comment: Apologies, I misread your post.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the fruits come from a field "Fruit" in your dataset, I would write something like this on the expression for the field where you want to set the summary:

```
= "Bananas: " & Sum(Iif(Fields!Fruit.Value = "Banana", 1, 0)) & Environment.NewLine &
"Apples: " & Sum(Iif(Fields!Fruit.Value = "Apple", 1, 0)) & Environment.NewLine &
"Oranges: " & Sum(Iif(Fields!Fruit.Value = "Orange", 1, 0)) & Environment.NewLine
```

See this --> [Reporting Services - Count Column Values if equals A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892911/reporting-services-count-column-values-if-equals-a)

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find something related to grouping in SSRS

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379581/grouping-in-ssrs
```

Comment: I'm referring to SSRS.